# How to simulate a control system with RK4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, control-theory, simulation, runge-kutta-methods

My question is simple yet I could not find answer on the internet. When I have a system described by its differential equation, I can simulate its states from time steps to time steps with RK4. But what to do when I want to put an acting force into the system which I control. In RK4 I should know what value I am going to give into the system in the next time step. So far I tried to predict this value by the derivative of the input force. Can someone recommend me literature in this field? Or give me tips what to do in this case?

Comment: You either formulate this as Delay-Differential Equation, where you would need to interpolate the history of the solution with order at least 3 (save a table of values and derivatives, use cubic polynomials) or you need to extend the system to also contain integral terms that enter the control, for a very simple example of that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810439/is-there-a-better-way-to-simulate-pid-control-in-python-with-scipys-solve-ivp/61006681#61006681 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487631/damped-oscillation-in-a-path/4487857#4487857

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that you put acting force into the system which you control? Do you mean a predefined known signal in time, that you choose? Is the input a function of the state itself? Or something entirely different even?

Comment: I  can manipulate the input force, in the question I am interested in arbitrary input force, where its value is not known at the next time step.

Comment: @KristófNémeth Imagine you are given the task to solve $f(x)=0$ for $x$. You would probably ask "what is $f$"? For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, you can solve the equation. But if its an arbitrary function and you have no information at all, its not possible to compute a solution. The same is true for differential equations, independently of the solver/RK4. You should add more details to your question, as it is vague at the moment. Maybe you have an input trajectory and only want to know how to simulate that? At least your comment about "predicting the next value" hints at that (predict from what?)

Comment: I ask this question in general, but this time I was examining the following equation:
$$\frac{d\omega (t)}{dt}=\frac{-b\ A^2\ \omega (t)\ sin^2(\omega (t) t)+M(t)}{Θ}$$
Here the $b$ is a damping constant, $A$ is a displacement amplitude, $\omega (t)$ is the angular velocity of the flywheel, and $M(t)$ is the input torque. And my question is that, how to simulate the system, when I don't know the future of the input torque $M(t)$.

Comment: @KristófNémeth It is unclear what you mean by "future of the input". The derivative of $\omega$ at time $t$ depends on $M$ at time $t$, which is the present value. So, if you have for example a feedback controller like $M(t)=-k \omega(t)$, you only need the present value of $M(t)$.

Comment: @SampleTime The RK4 method that I use to model the system has terms like $f(\omega(t+\frac{h}{2}),M(t+\frac{h}{2}))$ (where h is the timestep). It calculates the future value from the present derivative, which is clear to me in case of no input. But when there is an input, it needs its future value doesn't it?